# Knapsack like problem with nonnegative weight constraint

Tags: combinatorial-optimization, integer-programming

I am dealing with a knapsack-like problem with one difference from the conventional problem: the “weights” can be positive or negative and the constraint is $\sum w_i x_i \ge 0$ instead of $\sum w_i x_i \le W$. The "values" can also be positive or negative.

Can this be transformed to a knapsack problem or is it some other type of combinatorial optimization problem?

Comment: This is better suited to https://or.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Are the values all positive? If so, we should certainly take all items with positive weights, and then the question of the best subset of negative-weight items seems to be classical knapsack again.

Comment: Good point! Forgot to mention that values can also be negative.

Comment: What type of variable is $x$?

Comment: Binary indeed as you noted

Comment: Cross-posted: https://mathoverflow.net/q/405353/37212, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/144449/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $x_i$ is binary, perform a change of variables $\bar{x}_i:=1-x_i$ where $w_i>0$:
\begin{align}
\sum_i w_i x_i 
&= \sum_{i:w_i>0} w_i x_i + \sum_{i:w_i<0} w_i x_i \\
&= \sum_{i:w_i>0} w_i(1-\bar{x}_i) + \sum_{i:w_i<0} w_i x_i \\
&= \sum_{i:w_i>0} w_i + \sum_{i:w_i>0} (-w_i)\bar{x}_i + \sum_{i:w_i<0} w_i x_i
\end{align}
So $\sum_i w_i x_i \ge 0$ is equivalent to
$$\sum_{i:w_i>0} w_i\bar{x}_i + \sum_{i:w_i<0} (-w_i) x_i \le \sum_{i:w_i>0} w_i$$